# Accessing protected member functions from test code in C++

Tags: c++, testing, protected

I've been racking my brain trying to think of the best way to access a protected member function from some test code in C++, here's my problem:

```
//in Foo.h 
Class Foo
{
protected:
    void DoSomething(Data data);
}

//in Blah.h
Class Blah
{
public:
    Foo foo;
    Data data; 
};

//in test code...
Blah blah;
blah.foo.DoSomething(blah.data); // Here's my problem!
```

Some possible solutions so far:

Make the test code class a friend of Foo, but this pollutes Foo with test code

Make DoSomething a public function

I've looked at creating a test wrapper for Foo, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127616/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-a-protected-method-in-c), however this won't work as Blah contains the instance of Foo.

All advice/insight/opinions are most welcome!

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to test the protected method? I believe you should test the public interfaces of the class and leave the internal implementation to the class itself.

Comment: @AraK, i'm sorry to see you deleted your answer. It was nearly right, but you should have done `&test::DoSomething` instead of `&Foo::DoSomething` - that's the important thing in that trick, because it makes access checking go fine. Since you were first to answer tell me if you wanna undelete your answer and i will remove my answer below!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127616/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-a-protected-method-in-c

Comment: Umm why wouldn't you just create a derived class? Every answer I see here undermines the entire purpose of object orientation. Inheritance exists for a reason!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, since you said it is only a test code I am going to suggest something seriously hacky but would work:

```
struct tc : protected Foo
{
    tc(Foo *foo, Data& data)
    {
        ((tc*)foo)->DoSomething(data);
    }
};

Blah blah;
tc t(&blah.foo, blah.data);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions. I decided to go with this solution for now.

Answer (score 18):

There is a way which is completely allowed by the Standard.

```
//in Foo.h 
class Foo
{
protected:
    void DoSomething(Data data);
};

//in Blah.h
class Blah
{
public:
    Foo foo;
    Data data; 
};

//in test code...
struct FooExposer : Foo {
  using Foo::DoSomething;
};

Blah blah;
(blah.foo.*&FooExposer::DoSomething)(blah.data);
```

Read the [Hidden features of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/1065606#1065606) entry for an explanation.

---

You may write a macro for your convenience (the parenthesis are there so that you can use this macro also for types that have a comma, like `vector<pair<A, B>>`):

```
#define ACCESS(A, M, N) struct N : get_a1<void A>::type { using get_a1<void A>::type::M; }

template<typename T> struct get_a1;
template<typename R, typename A1> struct get_a1<R(A1)> { typedef A1 type; };
```

The matter now becomes

```
ACCESS((Foo), DoSomething, GetDoSomething);
Blah blah;
(blah.foo.*&GetDoSomething::DoSomething)(blah.data);
```

Comment: Fine indeed. A pity it would not work with `private` methods.

Comment: For those that want to do this a lot, grab the templates from above, then add: #define ACCESS(A, M) struct M##_struct : get_a1<void A>::type { using get_a1<void A>::type::M; }
#define CALL(B, M) ((B).*&M##_struct::M)
To use this: do ACCESS((Foo), DoSomething) at the top of your program. Then do CALL(foo, DoSomething)(arg1, arg2) to call the protected method.

Comment: [this](http://ideone.com/keDOxd) fails in VS2015 update 3: `error C2440: '.*': cannot convert from 'A *' to 'B *'`, only for member functions, compiles fine for member variables

Comment: actually, it doesn't compile also on VS2012 and VS2013, is this VC++ compiler non conformance to C++ standard?

Comment: @AndyT I have no idea. I suspect that it's non conformance. But it's too long since I've written the code, so I forgot.

Answer (score 7):

On the one hand, **don't do that**.

On the other hand, here's a gamble:

```
#define protected public
#include "foo.h"
#undef protected
```

8-)

But seriously, why is `DoSomething()` protected?  Probably because calling it from external code can break something.  In which case, you shouldn't be calling it from your tests.

Comment: Wouldn't friending be a better way to go here, if you absolutely have to test protected members (which I agree, you shouldn't be doing).

Comment: @Dominic: Yes, but @sarah explicitly doesn't want to use `friend`.

Comment: And this hack works (sometimes) when you have the header and a library, but not source, for the classes you want to exercise.

Comment: (to be fair, you do not recommend this, so this comment is not against your answer, but just against that technique). This probably works when "foo.h" is actually just a file with one class and nothing else, so you have complete control over this. But I would not do this, as anything that header includes indirectly will be affected too. Probably a whole other piece of code. It could cause a different ABI interface which can cause strange effects - you never know what the compiler does internally - maybe it orders member by their accessibility, or something.

Comment: @RichieHindle - I'm going to reassess whether the function needs to be protected in the first place. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3):

I've done

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    void DoSomething(Data data);
public:
    #ifdef TEST
    void testDoSomething(Data data);
    #endif
}
```

Then compile your unit tests with g++ -D TEST.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than ifdefing `private` to `public`, consider **ifdefing friendship**, or better yet think if that function *really* needs to belong to that class, maybe it would suffice to have something in a named/unnamed namespace in a cpp, and then declared in a test project.

Anyway, check [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#testing-private-code) link, maybe your testing framework would provide similar functionality.

**EDIT:** Did you consider inheriting your test class from your real class?

Answer (score 2):

You could use inheritance with forwarding functions:

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    void DoSomething(Data data);
}

class test_Foo : public Foo
{
public:
    void testDoSomething(Data data)
    {
        DoSomething(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to combine this with Dependency Injection so you can replace the Foo in Blah with a test_Foo instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use wrapper as follows:

```
// Foo.h unchanged

// Blah.h unchanged

// test code
class FooTest : public Foo { friend void test(); }; // make friends

void test()
{
    Blah blah;
    static_cast<FooTest*>(&blah.foo)->DoSomething(blah.data); // Here's no problem!    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is strictly test code, you could do...

```
#define protected public
#include "Foo.h"

// test code

#undef protected
```