# Testing protected member with googletest

Tags: c++, inheritance, testing, googletest, protected

I'm confused regarding inheritance when googletesting. I have a `class A` that has `protected` attributes. If I want to access those i have to extend that class, but at the same time i also need to extend `public ::testing::Test` for the sole purpose of `gtest`.

What is the most elegant solution to this problem?
Also I'm trying to avoid `#define protected public`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a FRIEND_TEST declaration, which is used in the header of tested class. Basically it defines the test as a friend of the class. In my use case, we disable all test includes when compiling in RELEASE mode, so it doesn't do any harm the real executable.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md)

Comment: just what  i needed, tnx :)

Comment: The link to the documentation has moved here: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md

Comment: New location is [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md).

Answer (score 25):

To avoid leaving traces of tests in the tested class use multiple-inheritance with a fixture:

```
class ToBeTested
{
protected:
    bool SensitiveInternal(int p1, int p2); // Still needs testing
}

// Google-test:
class ToBeTestedFixture : public ToBeTested, public testing::Test
{
   // Empty - bridge to protected members for unit-testing
}

TEST_F(ToBeTestedFixture, TestSensitive)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(SensitiveInternal(1, 1));
    ASSERT_FALSE(SensitiveInternal(-1, -1));
}
```

Comment: Got stuck here because this only seems to work if ToBeTested only has a no-arg constructor. In my case, I have an arg'd constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a combination of [Rene's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76628309/6271889) and [lisu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337320/6271889) answers to solve the problem of non-default constructors:

```cpp
class ToBeTested
{
public:
    ToBeTested() = delete;

    ToBeTested(int p): p1(p) {}

protected:
    bool SensitiveInternal(int p2) {return p1 == p2;}// Still needs testing

    const int p1;
};

// Stub to bridge the acess restrictions:
class ToBeTestedStub : public ToBeTested
{
public:
    ToBeTestedStub(int p):ToBeTested(p) {}
    FRIEND_TEST(ToBeTestedFixture, TestSensitive);
};


// Google-test:
class ToBeTestedFixture : public testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        stub = std::make_unique<ToBeTestedStub>(1);
    }

    // Using a pointer so we can instantiate the stub in the SetUp method.
    std::unique_ptr<ToBeTestedStub> stub;
};

TEST_F(ToBeTestedFixture, TestSensitive)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(stub->SensitiveInternal(1));
    ASSERT_FALSE(stub->SensitiveInternal(2));
}
```

An alternative is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31544055/6271889):

```cpp
// Stub to bridge the acess restrictions:
class ToBeTestedStub : public ToBeTested
{
public:
    ToBeTestedStub(int p):ToBeTested(p) {}
    using ToBeTested::SensitiveInternal;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement a stub class B which inherits the base class A.
Class B then provides all the protected methods of class A as public.
That way you can instanciate a object of the stub object and take it under test as usual.

```
class Base
{
 public:
  Base(int x);
  virtual ~Base()=default;
 
 protected:
  bool myMethod();
}

class stubBase : public Base
{
 public:
  stubBase(int x) : Base(x){}
  bool myMethod(){ Base::myMethod(); }
}

TEST(Base, myMethod)
{
  stubBase stub(1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(stub.myMethod());
}
```