# How to test a protected member from multiple inheritance in GoogleTest?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, googletest, protected

Imagine I have a `Foo` class which contains a `protected` member. `Foo` is my template base class.
Then I have a `Bar` class, which inherits from `Foo`.
The `protected` member will be private within `Bar`.

I need to make a test which I need to access the `protected` member from my `Foo` base class as seen below.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    int set() { mMember=1; }    
protected:
    int mMember;
};

class Bar : public Foo<int>
{};


namespace
{
    class myTestUT : public Foo<Bar>, public testing::Test { };

    TEST_F(myTestUT, how_can_i_test_this){
        Bar bar;
        bar.set(); // ALL GOOD, set() is public!

        ASSERT_EQ(bar.mMember, 1); // ERROR! mMember is protected! Why can't I access it since I am inheriting it?
    }
}
```

On my test setup I have `class myTestUT : public Foo<Bar>` which will be a bridge to have access to the Foo members (`public` and `protected`), so why can't I access my `mMember` method?

Please note that I know that `mMember` could be set on the constructor of `Foo`, but that is not the question here as I created this small snippet to illustrate my problem.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337123/testing-protected-member-with-googletest), but this doesn't contain my problem with multiple-inheritance.

Comment: You have to access it through `myTestUT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can't I access my mMember method?

It is not *my `mMember`*, it is `bar`'s member.

GoogleTest manual:

> When you need to test the private or protected members of a class,
> use the `FRIEND_TEST` macro to declare your tests as friends of the class.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void set() { mMember=1; }    
protected:
    int mMember;
    FRIEND_TEST(myTestUT, how_can_i_test_this);
};

class Bar : public Foo<int>
{};

class myTestUT : public Foo<Bar>, public testing::Test { };

TEST_F(myTestUT, how_can_i_test_this){
    Bar bar;
    bar.set();

    ASSERT_EQ(bar.mMember, 1);
}
```

You have to remove the unnamed namespace, or use a named namespace. https://godbolt.org/z/3h8q96Ecj

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the point where you’d access it a `friend` of your class, or expose a getter in the class (perhaps with some restrictions on access).