# Cast to child object for testing - is this code standard-conforming?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, memory-model

#### TL;DR

Is this casting/function call legal, standard-conforming C++11/14 code?
If not, would it be if there were no virtual functions (if `std::is_standard_layout<Module>` became true)?
(*NB: It works on every compiler I've tested it so far...*)

```cpp
class Module
{
protected:
    virtual float protectedVirtualFunction(float f) { return f*f*f; }
    float protectedFunction(float f) { return f*f; }
};

class ModuleTester : public Module // consists of ONLY aliases
{
public:
    using Module::protectedFunction;
    using Module::protectedVirtualFunction;
};

int main()
{
    Module module;  //assume this is a pre-existing instance
    // Is this legal?
    ModuleTester* testerMask = static_cast<ModuleTester*>(&module); 
    testerMask->protectedFunction(4.4f);
    testerMask->protectedVirtualFunction(4.4f);
}
```

#### Additional Information

Usually, I aim to test a classes public API only when writing UnitTests.
In some cases - like when you're dealing with legacy code you can't change - it's just more practical to access private members.

So, assuming we cannot change the design (DI, decoupling...), I see the following solutions:

1. Make private members public (compromising all encapsulation)
2. The ol' trick: `#define private public` in test context
3. The "Tester" pattern (as used in example code)

The standard way of using this "Tester" pattern would be like, and that should be legal:

```cpp
    ModuleTester tester;
    tester.protectedFunction(4.4f);
    tester.protectedVirtualFunction(4.4f);
```

However, sometimes I have an existing instance and it would be great if I could just apply this "tester mask" on top of it to gain access.

My guess is that as soon as I virtual functions and stop being "standard layout", there could be "undefined behaviour" strictly speaking. *However*, if I'm only defining aliases in the derived class, I don't see how this could go wrong as long as I use the same compiler for Module and ModuleTester.

**EDIT:** I found a similar method that doesn't use explicit pointer casting (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1725107/649700). It works, is arguably less readable and probably does not change the 'legality' status.

```
(module.*&ModuleTester::protectedVirtualFunction)(4.4f);
```

Other SO questions that make some good points:
[reinterpret_cast from object to first member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617519/reinterpret-cast-from-object-to-first-member),
[How do I unit test a protected method in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127616/how-do-i-unit-test-a-protected-method-in-c)

Comment: Another option would be to make the `class ModuleTester` a `friend` in `class Module` and (instead of inheriting) give it just a reference to `Module`. At least, you wouldn't need these scaring reinterprete casts. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11018d280a84875b). OK, that was stupid simple but stupid simple is not always bad. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff "Stupid simple" is often the smartest thing to do ^^ And it allows you to boast with "I'm programming in accordance with the KISS principle!"

Comment: True @Scheff, I forgot to mention the friend option... it still requires me to update the production code for every test class I use, though, that's why I dislike that solution.
That being said, it's definitely safe, but so is the "Tester Pattern" if I use it in the standard way (without casts)

Answer (score 1):

This would be Undefined Behavior since `&module` does not point at subobject of object `ModuleTester`:

> **8.5.1.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**
>   11 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B ”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D ”, where D is a class derived (Clause 13) from B , if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If B is a virtual base class of D or a base class of a virtual base class of D , or if
>   no valid standard conversion from “pointer to D ” to “pointer to B ” exists (7.11), the program is ill-formed. The null pointer value (7.11) is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B ” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D , the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

`#define private public` is also not a good idea:

> 2 A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 4, or to the attribute-tokens described in 10.6.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't one argue that `Module` and `ModuleTester` is technically the same object, since all that differentiates "parent and child" them are function aliases?

Comment: @SideLobe There is only `Module` object, no instances of `ModuleTester` class are created. C++ does not allow simply treating one object as another even if they have the same layout.